# Error when migrating from Apache Ignite to Hazelcast Camel component

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

I'm a newbie Hazelcast. I'm trying to migrate my application from Ignite apache camel component to Hazelcast. I changed my old code (Apache Ignite) with new one (Hazelcast).

**HazelCast**

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastOperationType">
    <constant>put</constant>
    </setHeader>
<to uri="hazelcast:map:${headers.token}" />
```

**Apache ignite**

```
    <setHeader headerName="CamelJCacheAction">
        <constant>PUT</constant>
        </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelJCacheKey">
    <simple>${headers.token}</simple>
        </setHeader>
    <to uri="jcache://accessTokensCache?cachingProvider=org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider&amp;cacheConfigurationProperties=#accessTokenJCacheConfigurationProperties&amp;expiryPolicyFactory=#accessTokenExpirePolicyFactory&amp;configurationUri=file:///{{application.base.dir}}/properties/ignite-config.xml" />
```

When i try to test the new code, i get this error :

```
 StackTrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null key is not allowed!
```

Could you please show me how to migrate my old code to Hazelcast ?

Is there any documentation explaining how to migrate from apache ignite to Hazelcast?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Camel ? According to [this line](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-hazelcast/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/hazelcast/map/HazelcastMapEndpoint.java#L31) it might be the syntax is `hazelcast-map` not `hazelcast.map`

Comment: Hello, my apache camel version is **2.17.5**

Comment: Did changing from dashes to dots help ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson I chnaged like this 

`<setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastOperationType">
                        <constant>put</constant>
                    </setHeader>
                    <setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastObjectId">
                        <simple>${headers.token}</simple>
                    </setHeader>
                    <to uri="hazelcast:map:accessTokensCache"/>`
it fix the error but it seems like it does not store the value in the map

Comment: `uri="hazelcast:map:accessTokensCache"` looks like it should be `uri="hazelcast-map:accessTokensCache"`